# Quick way to select inside a Fenced Code Block in Markdown using Vim

Tags: vim, markdown

How to conveniently select all content inside a Markdown **Fenced Code Block** using Vim?
For example, given a code block:

````
```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```
````

Assume the cursor is inside the block.
To select in Vim, I think we can have:

- go to the beginning of block

````
?```<CR>j
````

- visual select to the end of block

````
v/```<CR>k
````

(alternatively, select by paragraphs till the end)

```
v}}k
```

I am looking for simpler keystrokes or ideas, perhaps something similar to `vip` or `vi{`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the cursor is on the opening fence, I think the shortest method would be:

```
*kV''j
```

With the cursor on the closing fence, it would be:

```
#jV''k
```

With the cursor inside the code block, the approach would be different:

````
/```/-<CR>V??+<CR>
````

If that satisfies your needs, then you can stop reading now. If not, maybe we can try to come up with a comprehensive solution!

Let's start by breaking down the problem:

- select the content of a fenced code block,
- do so when the cursor is on the opening fence,
- do so when the cursor is between fences,
- do so when the cursor is on the closing fence,
- do nothing outside of those cases.

Then let's try our hands at the three cases:

- **The cursor is on the opening fence**

  Figuring out if the cursor is on a ```` ``` ```` is trivial:

  ````
  function! IsFence()
      return getline('.') == '```'
  endfunction!
  ````

  But, assuming this Markdown content:

  ````
  hello

  ```
  one
  two
  ```

  ```
  three
  four
  ```

  goodbye
  ````

  how can we figure out if we are on an opening fence or on a closing fence? Well, there are a few ways but the one I chose is to count the number of fences starting with the current one: if it is even, we are on an opening fence.

  ````
  function! IsOpeningFence()
      return IsFence() && getline(line('.'),'$')->filter({ _, val -> val =~ '^```'})->len() % 2 == 0
  endfunction
  ````

  Good!
- **The cursor is on the closing fence**

  Now that we can determine if the cursor is on a fence and if it is an opening one, determining if it is a closing fence is trivial:

  ```
  function! IsClosingFence()
      return IsFence() && !IsOpeningFence()
  endfunction
  ```

  Good!
- **The cursor is between fences**

  This one is a little bit trickier. There are, again, a few ways to go about it but the one I chose is to ask Vim whether the highlight group `markdownCodeBlock` is currently active:

  ```
  function! IsbetweenFences()
      return synID(line("."), col("."), 0)->synIDattr('name') =~? 'markdownCodeBlock'
  endfunction
  ```

  Good!

  NOTE: this snippet assumes that you use the built-in Markdown syntax script. If you don't, substitute `markdownCodeBlock` with whatever works for you.

Now that we can figure out which case we are in, let's see what we can do for each one.

- **The cursor is on the opening fence**

  ```
  if IsOpeningFence()
      normal *kV''j
  endif
  ```
- **The cursor is on the closing fence**

  ```
  if IsClosingFence()
      normal #jV''k
  endif
  ```
- **The cursor is between fences**

  Our original macro is not as trivial as the others to use with `:help normal` so we are going to try a different method:

  ````
  if IsBetweenFences()
      call search('^```', 'W')
      normal -
      call search('^```', 'Wbs')
      normal +
      normal V''
  endif
  ````

  where we…

  1. search forward for a ```` ``` ```` at the beginning of a line (the closing fence),
  2. move the cursor on the line above,
  3. search *backward*, this time, for a ```` ``` ```` at the beginning of a line (the opening fence) while leaving a mark behind us,
  4. move the cursor to the line below,
  5. enter visual-line mode from the current line to the line we marked earlier.

OK, let's put our decision tree together:

````
  if IsOpeningFence()
      normal *kV''j
  elseif IsBetweenFences()
      call search('^```', 'W')
      normal -
      call search('^```', 'Wbs')
      normal +
      normal V''
  elseif IsClosingFence()
      normal #jV''k
  else
      return
  endif
````

and consider the fact that what we do when we are between fences could also work when we are on the opening fence, which makes one branch redundant:

````
  if isOepeningFence() || IsBetweenFences()
      call search('^```', 'W')
      normal -
      call search('^```', 'Wbs')
      normal +
      normal V''
  elseif IsClosingFence()
      normal #jV''k
  else
      return
  endif
````

One last thing, it would be neater if we used the same approach in both branches so let's do it:

````
  if IsOpeningFence() || IsInside()
      call search('^```', 'W')
      normal -
      call search('^```', 'Wbs')
      normal +
      normal V''
  elseif IsClosingFence()
      call search('^```', 'Wbs')
      normal +
      normal V''k
  else
      return
  endif
````

Great! Let's put it all together in one single function:

````
function! SelectInnerCodeBlock()
    function! IsFence()
        return getline('.') =~ '^```'
    endfunction

    function! IsOpeningFence()
        return IsFence() && getline(line('.'),'$')->filter({ _, val -> val =~ '^```'})->len() % 2 == 0
    endfunction

    function! IsBetweenFences()
        return synID(line("."), col("."), 0)->synIDattr('name') =~? 'markdownCodeBlock'
    endfunction

    function! IsClosingFence()
        return IsFence() && !IsOpeningFence()
    endfunction

    if IsOpeningFence() || IsBetweenFences()
        call search('^```', 'W')
        normal -
        call search('^```', 'Wbs')
        normal +
        normal V''
    elseif IsClosingFence()
        call search('^```', 'Wbs')
        normal +
        normal V''k
    else
        return
    endif
endfunction
````

and map it in visual mode (for use with `v`) and operator-pending mode (for use with `y`, `d`, etc.):

```
xnoremap <silent> iC :<C-u>call SelectInnerCodeBlock()<CR>
onoremap <silent> iC :<C-u>call SelectInnerCodeBlock()<CR>
```

and see if it works:

[image: iC]

The last thing we need to do is make sure that our custom pseudo-text object is restricted to Markdown buffers. For that, we move our code to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`, with a few minor changes:

- `SelectInnerCodeBlock()` becomes script-local, see `:help :s` and `:help <SID>`,
- our mappings become buffer-local, see `:help <buffer>`.

````
" in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim
function! s:SelectInnerCodeBlock()
    function! IsFence()
        return getline('.') =~ '^```'
    endfunction

    function! IsOpeningFence()
        return IsFence() && getline(line('.'),'$')->filter({ _, val -> val =~ '^```'})->len() % 2 == 0
    endfunction

    function! IsBetweenFences()
        return synID(line("."), col("."), 0)->synIDattr('name') =~? 'markdownCodeBlock'
    endfunction

    function! IsClosingFence()
        return IsFence() && !IsOpeningFence()
    endfunction

    if IsOpeningFence() || IsBetweenFences()
        call search('^```', 'W')
        normal -
        call search('^```', 'Wbs')
        normal +
        normal V''
    elseif IsClosingFence()
        call search('^```', 'Wbs')
        normal +
        normal V''k
    else
        return
    endif
endfunction

xnoremap <buffer> <silent> iC :<C-u>call <SID>SelectInnerCodeBlock()<CR>
onoremap <buffer> <silent> iC :<C-u>call <SID>SelectInnerCodeBlock()<CR>
````